# Time Complexity of a for loop

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, big-o, time-complexity

So I'm not really understanding a few things here, when counting the steps in `for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)` the answer is:

1 for assignment `int i = 1`, n+1 for `i <= n` and n for `i++` which comes out to a total of 2n+2. My confusions is in 3 parts:

1.) Isn't the assignment `int i = 1;` also n? If lets say, n = 5, won't we end up assigning int i = 2, int i = 3... etc?

2.) For `i <= n`, is it n+1 because you are performing n checks and + 1 when it's false?

3.) Last, is `i++` n because you are performing n additions?

Comment: Looks like you need to develop some common sense and the ability to read and interpret a beginner Java tutorial. Do you **really** think that assigning 1 to a variable will assign 2 and 3 to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialization `int i=1;` is performed only one time at the beginning of the loop, regardless of n.

As for 2) and 3), you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

For loop looks like `for(INIT; CONDITION; INCREMENT) { /* ... */ }`. The INIT part executes once only. This is equivalent to:

```
INIT
while(CONDITION)
{ /* ... */
  INCREMENT
}
```